# Filter vector by vector

Tags: r

I have vectors:

```
a <- c(1,2,4,5,6)
b <- c(2,4,5)
```

A want to extract values from 'a' which are not in 'b', so desired output is:

```
1,6
```

How could i do that?

Answer (score 2):

We can use `setdiff`

```
setdiff(a, b)
#[1] 1 6
```

Or if there are duplicates

```
library(vecsets)
vsetdiff(a, b)
```

Or using `%in%` and `!`

```
a[! a %in% b]
```